# How can i start the camera and get frame from camera in IPhone

Tags: iphone, camera, frame

I have a app to do,but i'm a beginner,

1. start camera
2. start a thread
3. get current frame by thread
4. thread do something with image and get results
5. if the results of step-4 is not correctly then do step-3 until get correctly results

If anyone give me advice,so thanks!!!

if you have a sample ,that's will great!
Thanks one time!

Comment: Thanks a lot！

 1.I know should use UIImagePickerController and i know how to take a picture buy it,but i don't know how to catch the frame of camera into a Image object.　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　   

 2. I know  "Rome wasn't built in a day" also,but this is a Time-limited task，I have no more time。

Comment: First of all, you're commenting on the wrong post. Secondly, if you're new to iPhone development but insist on starting something that you have no idea about and aren't willing to research for, you'll fail. That's all I have to say. Re-read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What research have **you** done to combat this problem? Not much, because what you're saying is partly incorrect.

Let me explain in detail why:

1. The first thing you should always do when encountering such a problem is consult the Apple Developer Documentation. Everything public is well documented, so it should give you an idea where to start.
2. If you'd have looked there first, you would see that `UIImagePickerController` is responsible for Camera related tasks. `UIImagePickerController` belongs to `UIKit` - that's where point **2** of your question is entirely wrong - you're not allowed to make calls to `UIKit` from a secondary thread or you will encounter crashes/unexpected results. That's in the developer documentation too.
3. You need to understand that StackOverflow isn't a `give me the codez` website. If you have some code that you wrote yourself that doesn't work correctly, sure, post it and we'll help. But you've shown **no attempt** to have even researched the topic.

So please, check the [developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for more information.

If you're a beginner, I'd recommend the Stanford Podcasts. They provide an excellent start into iOS programing.

It'll take a while, but after all, Rome wasn't built in a day.